# Local Database Insert query does nothing

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I am trying to insert a row into the database. Below is my query:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Traindata.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Station (Naam, X, Y, Sporen) VALUES (@naam, @x, @y, @sporen)";

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naam", insert[1]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", insert[2]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", insert[3]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sporen", insert[4]);
        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error to save on database");
            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

When I run it nothing happens (Also no SQL errors).  What am I doing wrong? I am sorry if this is a stupid question, I am merely a beginner.

This should work (I have tested this with a select query that does work).

Comment: does it insert the record into the table?

Comment: That is the problem, it doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure this code is even being executed? `AddWithValue()` is not the best; better to create the parameter with a specified SqlDbType. Also, run SQL Server Profiler and watch to see what, if anything, is being submitted.

Comment: What's your **connection string**?

Comment: Make sure you're querying the right database.  Depending on your project setup you may be inserting to a file that is copied to a different location when the project is built.

Comment: Why you are assigning conn two times to command object?

Comment: @Piyush, would it matter how many times?  For the case at hand, I mean.

Comment: I only have one database in this project. My connection string: `Data Source = (LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Traindata.mdf;Integrated Security=True` - I got this from Property settings.

Comment: @ Cyberherbalist, ya not matter at most but not good practice

Comment: Put a breakpoint in, execute code step-by-step, make sure it is indeed executed

Comment: SO it is not inserting into the dataase that gets recreated every time you hit the build button? Yeah.

Comment: @SimonaJensen just a try: anything different happens if you do it without `dbo`: `"INSERT INTO Station (Naam, X, Y, Sporen) VALUES (@naam, @x, @y, @sporen)";
`

Comment: @YuriyGalanter this still doesn't do anything.

Comment: @TomTom What do you mean recreated?

Comment: try Int32 rowsRet = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); And see what is is returning.  Do you have unique or PK constraints you may be violating?  And I would put close in a finally.

Comment: @Blam it returns a 1.

Comment: If it says it inserts one row then I would tend to believe it.  Are you sure you are testing the correct table that the row was inserted?

Comment: well when I go to server explorer and right click the table and select data it shows nothing but a row that I manually inserted there before. And my select query in my project also just returns that row (when I select *).

Comment: Please try my code that has rowsRet.  Are you sure you are right clicking the correct table?

Comment: I voted to close.  No sample code to reproduce the problem and user has dropped their account.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried storing the query on a stored procedure and calling it from C#? ... Thats actually easier than making the query via hard code inside the C# code ... Just create a stored procedure that does whatever you want it to do, then call it from C# and add the parameters. It should look something like this:

```
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Your_Conection_String_s_Name"].ConnectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = "dbo.Your_Stored_Procedure";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Input_Param_1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 18).Value = "C#_Parameter1";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Input_Param_2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value = "C#Parameter_2";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Input_Param_3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value = "C#Parameter_3";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Input_Param_4", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "C#Parameter_4";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Input_Param_5", SqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value = "C#Parameter_5";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Output_Parameter_1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Output_Parameter_2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                "C#Output_Parameter_1" = "" + cmd.Parameters["@Output_Parameter_1"].Value;
                "C#Output_Parameter_2" = "" + cmd.Parameters["@Output_Parameter_2"].Value;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: So, create an SP for every single query?

Comment: How would I add a procedure? do you have a link to a good tutorial or anything similar?

Comment: You can add a new stored procedure in the SQL server management studio ... Just find your DB and find a folder named Programmability, inside that folder is the Stored Procedure´s folde ... And yes, you should create a SP for every differetn quesry, but you can recycle them, so, you can call the same SP infinite number of times, you just need to find a way to make it modular.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a type mismatch
If x, y are not int then substitute in the correct type

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Traindata.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = SqlCommand.CreateCommand())
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            command.Query = "select count(*) from dbo.Station";
            Int32 rowsRet = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();
            Console.WriteLine(rowsRet.ToString());

            command.Query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Station (Naam, X, Y, Sporen) VALUES (@naam, @x, @y, @sporen)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naam", insert[1]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@x", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters["@x"].Value = Int32.Parse(insert[2]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@y", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters["@y"].Value = Int32.Parse(insert[3]);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sporen", insert[4]);       
            rowsRet = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine(rowsRet.ToString());

            command.Query = "select count(*) from dbo.Station";
            Int32 rowsRet = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();
            Console.WriteLine(rowsRet.ToString());
        }
        catch (SqlException exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error to save on database");
            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
        }
        finally 
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        // op claims the insert is gone the next time the programs is run 
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            command.Query = "select count(*) from dbo.Station";
            Int32 rowsRet = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();
            Console.WriteLine(rowsRet.ToString());
        }
        catch (SqlException exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error to save on database");
            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
        }
        finally 
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The count does become 2 after its added, but if I rerun the program it starts at 1 and becomes 2 again. It doesn't save like it should?

Comment: It is not that I don't believe you but that is bizarre.  See update.